# modifying something in a "list of lists of tuples" structure without destroying the structure in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

It sounds like a simple question. But, given a:

```
a = [[(1,2)], [(3,4), (5,6)], [(7,8), (9,10), (11,12)]]
```

How can I add 1 to each of the first item in the tuples, so that I get the follwing?

```
b = [[(2,2)], [(4,4), (6,6), [(8,8), (10,10), (12,12)]]
```

I tried a code as follows:

```
b = []

for list_of_tuples in a:
    for num1, num2 in list_of_tuples:
        b.append((num1+1, num2))

b
```

But, this destroys the original structure. So, How can I get what I want, using two for-loops?

Answer (score 4):

Using a nested list comprehension:

```
>>> a = [[(1,2)], [(3,4), (5,6)], [(7,8), (9,10), (11,12)]]
>>> b = [[(x+1, y) for x, y in tuples] for tuples in a]
>>> b
[[(2, 2)], [(4, 4), (6, 6)], [(8, 8), (10, 10), (12, 12)]]
```

As a `for` with a list comprehension:

```
b = []
for tuples in a:
    b.append([(x+1, y) for x, y in tuples])
```

Without any list comprehension:

```
b = []
for tuples in a:
    tuples_b = []
    for x, y in tuples:
        tuples_b.append((x+1, y))
    b.append(tuples_b)
```

Comment: oh, this is great.. I tried a list comprehension.. but, I had b = [(x+1, y) for x, y in tuples for tuples in a], which means that I didn't embed one in the other..!!

Comment: +1. As a general rule, whenever you find yourself trying to figure out how to modify a structure in place, ask whether you can instead use a comprehension to generate a new copy. It's sometimes impossible, or too complicated, or too space-inefficient, but most of the time it's the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

using `map()` and `isinstance()`:

```
def func(x):
    if isinstance(x,list):
       return map(func,x)
    elif isinstance(x,tuple):
        return (x[0]+1,x[1])

a = [[(1,2)], [(3,4), (5,6)], [(7,8), (9,10), (11,12)]]
print map(func,a)
```

**output:**

```
[[(2, 2)], [(4, 4), (6, 6)], [(8, 8), (10, 10), (12, 12)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You are almost on right track, but you also need to add the container list for tuples first into b, to recreate original structure

```
a = [[(1,2)], [(3,4), (5,6)], [(7,8), (9,10), (11,12)]]

b = []

for list_of_tuples in a: 
    b.append([])
    for num1, num2 in list_of_tuples: 
        b[-1].append((num1+1, num2))

print b
```

output:

```
[[(2, 2)], [(4, 4), (6, 6)], [(8, 8), (10, 10), (12, 12)]]
```

Comment: Thanks, but what does b[-1] mean over there?

Comment: b[-1] means last item in list b, we added a list to b and are now accessing it, so that we can append tuples to it

Answer (score 0):

Are you stuck with tuples?  It might be better to convert them to lists, since you're clearly modifying them.